# Marketing Cloud Connector Batch Size

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

What is the batch size marketing cloud connector uses to move data from SFDC to SFMC?
Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are referring to the Data Stream feature. We were informed by Salesforce (during a Webinar on the Salesforce Marketing Cloud Connector) that you can sychronize up to 2.5M records per hour.

I'm not sure what would happen if you attempt to synchronize more records than this threshold.